# react-intersection-observer only works with the last elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref, react-intersection-observer

I'm trying to build the Lazy Loading feature with `react-intersection-observer`, the goal is to only load the images in the boxes if they're in the viewport.

- Currently, when I scroll to the last elements - it will render out all of the images of the boxes.
- But when I scroll up and the last boxes are out of the viewport, everything on top will disappear.
- If I print out `inView`, this turns to `true` when scrolling to the last elements and turns `false` when the last elements are out of the viewport.

How to fix this problem so it will only render out the boxes that are in the viewport?

---

### Demo gif:

[image]

---

### My code:

**App.js**

```
export const AppContext = createContext();

function App() {
  const { ref, inView, entry } = useInView({
    rootMargin: "50px 0px",
    initialInView: true
    // triggerOnce: true,
  });

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ ref, inView, entry }}>
      <div className="App">
        <Posts />
      </div>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Post.js**

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { AppContext } from '../App'

function Post({ post }) {
  const { ref, inView } = useContext(AppContext)
  return (
    <div className="post" ref={ref}>
      {inView ? 
        <img src={post.imgUrl} alt={post.title} className="post__img" loading="lazy" />
        : <div className="post__img" />
      }
      <h1 className="post__title">{post.title}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Post
```

### Update:

I updated the Codesandbox link below to move `useInView` to `Post.js` and removed the Context API. It works now!

[image: Edit Lazy Loading with react-intersection-observer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you are using context, it maintains a single state but in your case you want to track all post items separately so,

Just bring the **useInView** hook inside each component of Post.js and remove it from App.js

Comment: It works! Wow I made it complicated using context :) Thank you!